# How to get HL7 templates for Mirth Connect?

Tags: oracle, hl7, mirth, ora-00911

I'm new to this HL7 standard, but earlier I worked on NCPDP standard. Now I'm trying to explore Mirth Connect open source tool. When I'm trying to configure as per the documentation(User Guide) which is provided in http://www.mirthcorp.com/community/wiki/display/mirthuserguidev1r8p0/Message+Builder
URL, but in this documentation it is mention to use HL7 template. I don't where to get these templates. Could you please help me.

I searched in internet and some where forums I found following example template

MSH|^~\&|MIRTH_1.7|DOMAIN|LABTEST||${date.get('yyyyMMddHHmm')}||ADT^A08|${UUID}|P|1.7|||AL|NE|
EVN|A08|${date.get('yyyyMMddHHmm')}||||
PID|||${patno}||${family_name}^${first_name}^${middle_name}^^^^||${d_o_b}|${sex}|||${address1}^${address2}^${address3}^^^^||${phone}|${emp_phone}||${marital_status}|${religion}|||||||||||
PV1||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||

When I used this and try to run the channel I'm getting following exception in **Events**

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00911: invalid character
 Query: SELECT PATIENTINFO.PATIENTID AS PATIENTINFO_PATIENTID, 
PATIENTINFO.FIRSTNAME AS PATIENTINFO_FIRSTNAME, 
PATIENTINFO.LASTNAME AS PATIENTINFO_LASTNAME 
FROM PATIENTINFO;

 Parameters: []
    at org.apache.commons.dbutils.QueryRunner.rethrow(QueryRunner.java:359)
    at org.apache.commons.dbutils.QueryRunner.query(QueryRunner.java:240)
    at com.webreach.mirth.connectors.jdbc.JdbcMessageReceiver.getMessages(JdbcMessageReceiver.java:255)
    at org.mule.providers.TransactedPollingMessageReceiver$1.doInTransaction(TransactedPollingMessageReceiver.java:91)
    at org.mule.transaction.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:72)
    at org.mule.providers.TransactedPollingMessageReceiver.poll(TransactedPollingMessageReceiver.java:104)
    at org.mule.providers.PollingMessageReceiver.run(PollingMessageReceiver.java:90)
    at org.mule.impl.work.WorkerContext.run(WorkerContext.java:290)
    at edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:650)
    at edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:675)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

{}
```

and in Server Logs

```
[2010-07-28 19:02:52,515]  FATAL (org.mule.impl.DefaultComponentExceptionStrategy:83): The Default Component Exception Strategy has been invoked but there is no current event on the context


[2010-07-28 19:02:52,515]  FATAL (org.mule.impl.DefaultComponentExceptionStrategy:84): The error is: ORA-00911: invalid character
 Query: SELECT PATIENTINFO.PATIENTID AS PATIENTINFO_PATIENTID, 
PATIENTINFO.FIRSTNAME AS PATIENTINFO_FIRSTNAME, 
PATIENTINFO.LASTNAME AS PATIENTINFO_LASTNAME 
FROM PATIENTINFO;

 Parameters: []
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00911: invalid character
 Query: SELECT PATIENTINFO.PATIENTID AS PATIENTINFO_PATIENTID, 
PATIENTINFO.FIRSTNAME AS PATIENTINFO_FIRSTNAME, 
PATIENTINFO.LASTNAME AS PATIENTINFO_LASTNAME 
FROM PATIENTINFO;

 Parameters: []
    at org.apache.commons.dbutils.QueryRunner.rethrow(QueryRunner.java:359)
    at org.apache.commons.dbutils.QueryRunner.query(QueryRunner.java:240)
    at com.webreach.mirth.connectors.jdbc.JdbcMessageReceiver.getMessages(JdbcMessageReceiver.java:255)
    at org.mule.providers.TransactedPollingMessageReceiver$1.doInTransaction(TransactedPollingMessageReceiver.java:91)
    at org.mule.transaction.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:72)
    at org.mule.providers.TransactedPollingMessageReceiver.poll(TransactedPollingMessageReceiver.java:104)
    at org.mule.providers.PollingMessageReceiver.run(PollingMessageReceiver.java:90)
    at org.mule.impl.work.WorkerContext.run(WorkerContext.java:290)
    at edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:650)
    at edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:675)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Please help me in resolving this issue.

Thanks.
Student

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Exception is gone when I removed semicolon(;) at the end of the query(which came with auto generated query).

Regarding the templates I'm still not sure. I heard from someone that we have to create manually based on the HL7 standard.

Answer (score 2):

I'd ask your partner company for some samples, or search the Mirth forums to find a couple.

The sample you have could be cleaned up.  Replace the coded elements with "real" data.  For example, {date.get('yyyyMMddHHmm')} should be replaced with a real date string, '2010-08-20'.

Also, I found that when pasting samples into the template box, I had to separate each segment (add crlf's inbetween).
So instead of MSH|...ADT|...PID|..., you get:
   MSH|...
   ADT|...
   PID|...

Hope that helps.